# Ruby Rack app reverse proxy with Nginx

Tags: ruby, nginx, rack, reverse-proxy

Are there any good link/resources deploying a Rack app(Not rails!).

So far I have the Rack app set-up with the folders and such but I have been having **LOTS** of trouble with the nginx part so I uninstalled and decided to try again.

Maybe someone here give me a good dumbed-down version to do this task?

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

At this point, any guide for Rails 3 and up should work exactly like any other Rack app. So guides to setting up with Passenger, Unicorn, Thin or Puma should all work fine with your Rack app.